# JSON format in Google developers blogger

Tags: blogger, oauth2-playground

What is the JSON format for https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground when you insert posts in the blogger?

Answer (score 0):

The basic JSON format for inserting a new post via Blogger API is as follows -

```
{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "content": "Blog Content, can contain HTML",
  "blog": {
    "id": "BLOGID"
  },
  "title": "Blog Title",
  "labels": [
    "Label"
  ],
  "titleLink": "https://google.com",
  "status": "LIVE"
  "readerComments": "ALLOW",
  "location": {
    "lat": 0,
    "lng": 0,
    "name": "Place"
  }
}
```

You can try using the API Explorer for this endpoint at https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert